# Git alias with two commands not working but another commands is working

Tags: git, github, alias

I've created a alias to add all changes and commit for git, but not working.

Alias:

`git config --global alias.cam 'git add --all && git commit -m'`

When I try to use this alias I facing this error:

`expansion of alias 'cam' failed; 'git' is not a git command`

I ready have another alias and its working.

Comment: `git config --global alias.cam 'commit -am'`

Comment: As a sidenote, your version failed because it lacked a `!` at start to pass it to bash and handle the `&&` correctly. But apart from that it should work.

Comment: @RomainValeri work like charm. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

When you add aliases to git commands you don't include the word "git" on it.

For example: git config --global alias.co checkout, git config --global alias.br branch, git config --global alias.st status and so on.

I hope it helps.

Maybe this post can give you some guidance: https://hackernoon.com/git-going-with-aliases-a9706e23fa9c

Answer (score -1):

I did this and it seems to works:

[image]